# WPF Window don't display element inherited from Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I want that all my actions for drawing graph were in my control, inherited from Canvas. But window don't display MyCanvas. I don't know why.

```
class MyCanvas : Canvas
    {
        private Double XTimeScale;
        private Double YAmpSacle;
        private Double YTopLimit;
        private Double YBotLimit;
        private List<Point> DotsGraph;

public MyCanvas(Double XTimeScale,
                                      Double YAmpSacle,
                                      Double YTopLimit,
                                      Double YBotLimit)
        {
            this.XTimeScale = XTimeScale;
            this.YAmpSacle = YAmpSacle;

            this.YTopLimit = YTopLimit;
            this.YBotLimit = YBotLimit;
            this.Height = (YTopLimit + YBotLimit);
        }

        public List<Line> DrawNet(Double Width, Double Height)
        {
            List<Line> temp = new List<Line>();
            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
            brush.Color = Colors.Gray;

            for (int i = 0; i < Width; i+= 10)
            {
                Line Y = new Line();
                Y.Stroke = brush;
                Y.StrokeThickness = 1;
                Y.Y1 = 0;
                Y.Y2 = Height;
                Y.X1 = i;
                Y.X2 = i;
                temp.Add(Y);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < Height; j += 10)
            {
                Line X = new Line();
                X.Stroke = brush;
                X.StrokeThickness = 1;
                X.X1 = 0;
                X.X2 = Width;
                X.Y1 = j;
                X.Y2 = j;
                temp.Add(X);
            }
            foreach (var t in temp)
                this.Children.Add(t);
            return temp;
        }
}
```

And the class of windows where MyCanvas should be displayed. I added it to Grid:

```
public partial class ShowCanvas : Window
{
    public ShowCanvas()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         MyCanvas EAP = new MyCanvas(300, 300, 300, 300);

         Base.Children.Add(EAP); // Base is Grid on window ShowCanvas
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using Grid.SetColumn(EAP, 1); ?

Comment: It could be, that your grid is the one doing problems. Did you make everything variable, so that the canvas would not vanish inside one of the cells inside the grid?

Comment: How do you know it's not shown? You never call the DrawNet method.

Comment: you are creating your class (i.e. window) with name `ShowCanvas`. But the constructor name in the class is different and I didn't understand how it works for you. you are writing the statement `Base.Children.Add` and how this will add your MyCanvas to the current window and Visible?

Comment: @SamY, I just add this row of code and it doesnt help. I'm not really shure about did i do everything varible. Seems not.

Comment: @Ramesh Babu, so sorry, but its a misprint.((

Comment: @Clemens, this method belongs to...?

Comment: As Clemens hints at, can you show the code that calls the method DrawNet in your MyCanvas class?

Comment: Please post the clear minimalistic project, which illustrates your problem. Otherwise we will not be able to reproduce your issue

Comment: what is this funktion public EnergyArrivalPresenter? I don't see a constructor in your class. if EnergyArrivalPresenter should be it, then you have to name it the same as your class name.
And you don't use your DrawNet. Put a function call for it into your constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your window did display your canvas, but your canvas didn't have any children. Call DrawNet method.

You can use an open-source program called "Snoop" to navigate through the visual tree and see properties of visuals

[image]

Comment: Уeah, that's really a problem, thak you all very much for wast time for my stupidity minute.